# Javascript: select option value --> button name

Tags: javascript

I need the selected value to my form submit button.

The reasion is because when the value is "yes" there is a post called if (isset($_POST['yes']) and for "no" there is another if (isset($_POST['no']))

So all i need is:

```
<select>
<option value"yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

And this value must be updated here:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send form" name="Value from the select option">
```

Comment: what javascript have you written?

Comment: Your post keys are actual possible values? Is it possible for you to have a static name like "selected_answer" for instance? So that you don't have to manually update the input's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onChange event in the select to get and change the button name

```js
function updateBtn(sel) {
    
  document.getElementById('sendForm').setAttribute('name', sel.value);
  
  }
```

```html
<select onChange="updateBtn(this)">
<option value"yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="sendForm"  value="Send form" name="Value from the select option">
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `name` attribute to `select` element

```
<select name="userSelected">
  <option value"yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Now use in php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['userSelected'])){
    if($_POST['userSelected'] == 'yes'){
      /* code for yes */
    }else{
      /* code for no */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e){

   e.target.querySelector('input[type=submit]').name = e.target.querySelector('select').value;

});
```

```html
<form action="">
  
  <select>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="">

</form>
```

And if you really want it on the `select`, do like this instead of inline script

*Note: Make sure you have set the input's name to the default of the select or else if no one change it, it has no value*

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener("change", function(e){

   e.target.form.querySelector('input[type=submit]').name = e.target.value;

});
```

```html
<form action="">
  
  <select>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="yes">

</form>
```

Comment: This way it added the name to the form and not to the button, but still thank you for your work :)

Comment: @Marvinoo_ And btw, should really avoid inline scripting like `onChange="updateBtn(this)"` for all the reasons one avoid inline styles, it is very much more difficult and unpractical to maintain.

Comment: @Marvinoo_ Check my 2:nd sample (and the note)